# Select Tag Options Filled In By User

Tags: ruby-on-rails

and thanks in advance for any help.

I have a business development application, that in one area of the app, allows users to scroll through a list of their business clients (a client list), which is the select tag.

But, in order the for application to learn who the user's clients are, the user needs to tell the application that information.

**My specific question is:** exactly how do you allow the user to add items to a select tag, or a drop down list they can then CHOOSE (choose one of the options). Be as detailed as you can w/ the explanation.

```
Here is the index page where I'm displaying the select tag. The options, have to come from the user.

<div align="left"><%= DateTime.now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') %></div>

<div align="center"><%= "WELCOME TO DEFINITION, RYAN" %></br></br>
<div align="center"><%= "SALIENCE9 CORPORATION" %></br>

</br><div align="center"><%= image_tag "ryan_bottom_footer.png" %></div></br> 

<%= select_tag "Current Clients", options_for_select([ @client_list, "client1", "client2", "client 3" ]) %>

<%= submit_tag(value = "Save changes", options = {}) %>

<%= link_to 'Current Clients', :controller => 'current_clients', :action => 'index' %>    </br></br></br></br>

<%= link_to "Define", :controller => 'define_categories', :action => 'index' %> </br>

<%-#this should link to final stored action items %>

<%= link_to "Archived Action Items", :controller => 'questions', :action =>  'display_modes' %></br></br>

<%= link_to "Back Home", :controller => 'home', :action => 'index' %> </br></div>    </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>

<div align="left"><%= link_to "Switch Categories", :controller => 'define_categories', :action => 'index' %> </div></br>
```

I went as far as generating a "current client" model, knowing this might be on the right track. Which doesn't have anything in it.

```
class CurrentClient < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

In my extremely amateur understanding of rails, this is where I need more learning, and more reading. I understand views, controllers, routes, etc. Models, and this type of stuff, I'm still peddling through.

Thanks !

Comment: The short story is you'll want to read up about associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html (your User has_many Clients, and your Client belongs_to User)

Comment: That said, how does this syntactically work ?